# How does the media library determine if a PDF file has preview images?

Tags: media-library, pdf

When PDF preview images are available, how does the Media Library determine that it needs to display them? Does it check for a '_wp_attachment_metadata' record in the postmeta table? And where in Wordpress is the code that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preview images for PDF documents are created within `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` [[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L206)].

The full size preview image will have the `-pdf.jpg` extension [[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L261)].

The preview images info for the PDF document is stored in `_wp_attachment_metadata` in the post meta table.

Here's an example data for a `test.pdf` document:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sizes] => Array
                (
                    [thumbnail] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => test-pdf-116x150.jpg
                            [width] => 116
                            [height] => 150
                            [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                        )

                    [full] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => test-pdf.jpg
                            [width] => 1088
                            [height] => 1408
                            [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

This is stored as a serialized array under the `_wp_attachment_metadata` key in the post meta table, but we display it here as an array for better readability.

It's fetched with `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` [[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-includes/post.php#L5053)], as for any other image attachment.

We can see it e.g. in `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()` [[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-includes/media.php#L3083)].

Also in `image_downsize()`[[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-includes/media.php#L206)], that's used by `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` [[src]](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-includes/media.php#L824).

The latter one is used by `wp_get_attachment_image()`, that's called within the `column_title()` method of the media list table, to display the image preview [[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ee126d25670a3c8d44578046ee1e4e5f3a3f2057/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-media-list-table.php)].

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thus to automatically get the PDF preview image, one must use wp_get_attachment_image() instead of wp_get_attachment_thumb_url().

Comment: Both should work to fetch the pdf preview image, as both use `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`  implicitly. Just depends if you want HTML output or an url output. @AlanP

Comment: Yes, wp_get_attachment_thumb_url() does work now.

Comment: Great - I'm not sure if a preview image can be generated from every uploaded pdf document, e.g. from corrupted ones. So one should in general have a fallback @AlanP